# You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle without 'android:exported' property set but already been set in manifest file

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I do have a problem with my current flutter project. My project was already built in release and also I put also the correct keystore file and the targetsdkversion. Now, when I am uploading my app in the playstore it always shows android exported property set (which as I was already know how to solve it.) I set all the receivers and tags that uses intent-filter to android:exported' true or false. Now, the problem is when I upload it to playstore it still showing the android exported error. I tried to migrate it to android studio in order to modify the merged manifest but I am unable to do so because I doesn't show the merged manifest. I also tried to manually edit the one on the app/build/intermediates/merged_manifest folder but still same results. I am using latest flutter with dart for it. Any more tips for me to fix? Attached also here is my manifest file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jerrybuyer.app" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/>
        
   <application
        android:label="Jerry App"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" tools:node="merge">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

        <!-- facebook configs -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>

        
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:exported="true"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

PS: I have now managed to unlock my merged manifest but even though I saw the merged manifest file, it doesnt show any intent-filter that needs an android exported

[image: Here is the screenshot of the android merged-manifest that I managed to show. It doesn't show any errors regarding the intent-filter android:exported]

Here is the screenshot of the android merged-manifest that I managed to show. It doesn't show any errors regarding the intent-filter android:exported

Comment: I have now managed to unlock my merged manifest but even though I saw the merged manifest file, it doesnt show any intent-filter that needs an android exported.